# How to change tab programmatically?

Tags: rubymotion

I am creating an iOS app using RubyMotion. I would like to create a custom looking tabBar therefor I need to know how to change tab programmatically and how to get the current tab. Is this possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [motion-tab](https://github.com/clearsightstudio/motion-tab) to create the tab bar.

**Basic Usage** (from the Readme)

```
def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
  @window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)

  tabs = [
    {
      systemIcon: UITabBarSystemItemContacts,
      navigationController: true,
      viewController: ContactsViewController
    }, {
      title: "Custom",
      icon: "custom.png",
      navigationController: false,
      viewController: CustomViewController.alloc.initWithCustomInit(true)
    }, {
      title: "Settings",
      icon: "settings.png",
      navigationController: true,
      viewController: SettingsViewController
    }
  ]

  tabBarController = MotionTab::TabBar.createTabBarControllerFromData(tabs)
  MotionTab::TabBar.select(tabBarController, title: "Settings")
  # MotionTab::TabBar.select(tabBarController, tag: 0) # Selects first tab

  @window.rootViewController = tabBarController
  @window.makeKeyAndVisible
end
```

The gem doesn't have the current tab functionality now, but it wouldn't be too difficult to add a class attribute to `MotionTab::TabBar` that returns the current tab.